# shouldStartLoadWithRequest is called after webViewDidFinishLoad -Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview, ios9

In my `webView`'s delegate method I am checking for the condition when `webview` loading fully completes by using this code:

```
if ([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"]) {

    //Code to handle other things

    //Sometimes after this block shouldStartLoadWithRequest is called

}
```

Sometimes even control goes to if block even then `-shouldStartLoadWithRequest` this method is being called and my code breaks.

Is their any other alternative? I also tried `webview.isLoading` but this also doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't `webviewdidfinishload` method enough for your need? If you are loading a url I suggest using WKWebview - as recommended by Apple [WKWebview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview). It gives you more control than UIWebview.

Comment: @Teffi `webviewdidfinishload` is not working for me

Comment: As I've mentioned earlier I strongly suggest that you use _WKWebview_. `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` gets called every time a new request is called by the UIWebview. This is not exclusive to the initial load request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one workaround to stop any further execution of scripts after didFinishLoading.

I used following condition to stop reqeust:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
  {
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
   {
     //my code
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript and the userContentController as a way for your page to message back to your native code that it is loaded and ready. When you setup your WkWebView, setup the handler like this:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKUserContentController *controller = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"observe"];
theConfiguration.userContentController = controller;
CGRect statusBarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.y = statusBarFrame.size.height;
frame.size.height -= statusBarFrame.size.height;
self.primaryWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:theConfiguration];
```

Then add a method to your ViewController called userContentController, like this:

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController
    didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Check the details in message.body for what your javascript said
        NSLog(@"javascript message: %@", message.body);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do note that this might be an overkill for a simple feature of just getting notified once a request has been loaded. And this assumes that you have control over the page being initially loaded. Otherwise this wont work and that you have to inject js.